# iTunes Connect Customer Reviews Not Showing

Tags: app-store-connect

For my new game on the App Store I can't see a couple 1 and 2 star reviews I got. It only shows 3 of my 5 star reviews. I can't see them in iTunes or in iTunes Connect.

Answer (score 3):

Users can leave a star rating without leaving a review.  The 1 and 2 star "ratings" were probably not "reviews".